# BASH - GREP - invert much not working

Tags: bash, grep

I'm trying to find a number of open file descriptors by user "apache". I would like to exclude `ls: /proc/PID/fd: No such file or directory` but the GREP exclusing is not working:

```
# for pid in $(lsof -u apache | awk '{ print $2 }' | uniq); do ls -1 /proc/$pid/fd | grep -v "No"; done | wc -l 
ls: /proc/PID/fd: No such file or directory
1944
```

Comment: What about `>/dev/null` to delete error codes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `|& grep -v "No such file or directory"`

Unlike `|`, `|&` will also redirect the error output of `ls`

Comment: Thanks for your reply - for some reason it doesn't work for me `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `&'`

Comment: Maybe it's an old version of BASH :-/ Try `ls 2>&1 -1 /proc/$pid/fd | grep -v "No such file or directory"`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
for pid in $(lsof -u apache | tail -n +2 | awk '{ print $2 }' | uniq); do ls -1 /proc/$pid/fd ; done | wc -l
```